# Appropriate tuning of the MPPI controller for close goals

Tags: ros2, nav2

I have a problem tuning the MPPI controller parameters, which occurs when I specify a goal close to the robot. The robot radius is 0.22 and the motion model is DiffDrive. The problem occurs when I give the robot a goal whose x coordinate is nearly the same as the robot's and whose y coordinate is not much different. In this case, the robot should only move laterally, but since its motion model is DiffDrive, it cannot move laterally. The path planner plans a feasible path, so that the robot has to move forward and then back off at a small angle, for this maneuver I attach the following figure:

[image]

In the example above, the lateral distance of the goal is just outside the robot's footprint.

- In the case where I enable the GoalCritic parameter, the robot wants to go straight to the goal, so it doesn't follow the planned path and gets stuck in a local minimum. After several recoveries, the robot can finally reach its destination, but sometimes it takes several minutes.
- In the other case, when I didn't enable the GoalCritic parameter, the robot couldn't reach the goal. This case is shown in the picture above. The robot started on the planned path, but didn't follow it all the way, changed direction and followed the same path back to the starting point. Then the robot randomly backed off even further without going into recovery mode.

For the `GoalCritic`, `GoalAngleCritic`, `PathAlignCritic`, `PathFollowCritic`, `PathAngleCritic` parameters, I mainly changed the values of the `cost_weight` and `treshold_to_consider` parameters.

Is it possible to tune the controller to follow the planned trajectory for such close targets and to move the robot to the goal based on that? If so, do I need to enable the GoalCritic parameter? Which parameters do I need to set correctly for this to work?

Answer (score 0):

I'd have to be able to reproduce this situation and example locally to give you precise advice about what to change, but what you want is reasonable and you have all the tools at your disposal to accomplish it.

The threshold parameter on the goal/goal angle critics basically are when we should consider them, while in the path align/follow/angle they're the proximity to the goal when we should **ignore** them so that we can give control over to the goal/goal angle critics to do-their-thing to get a precise achievement of the goal possible.

My logic is that when you're within a meter or two of the goal, you really don't care much about what the global path says, you're really just interested in achieving that final pose and avoiding obstacles (who's critic is always on; there is no threshold param to disable). So my default tuning has that behavior, when you're close to the goal like in your example, we more or less ignore the path because we don't care about the specific way we get there, we just want to get there smoothly and accurately -- which the influence of the goal/goal angle and obstacle critics are more than atune to handle by themselves.

If you had a robot with a non-differential type, then we do care about the kinematic constraints, but we also have motion models for that. In that case, it would do a more forward->reverse like your images show, but on its own volition.

If you'd like to make it follow the path even very closely to the goal, you can reduce the path critics' threshold parameter to `0.0` so that it always considers them. Just note that you'll likely have to retune the goal/goal angle critics weights in their entirety since those throw the on-approach-to-final-goal tuning that I spent weeks on on your behalf. You may also have less accurate final goal pose achievement possible since you're introducing other things perturbing the accurate goal achievement (e.g. trying to align with a path).